# Группировка кластеров по признаку (например только в пределах района)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Скажите, как [это](https://rodnaya-vyatka.ru/places#layer=map&center=60.41024_49.48755&zoom=8) сделано, в частности, как можно сгруппировать вот таким образом кластеры, в зависимости от района? На сервере сделана группировка под нужный масштаб или в браузере так можно указать сгруппировать метки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как это сделано можно понять плотно ознакомившись непосредственно с сайтом, что вы привели в пример. Но основная идея берется отсюда:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

Параметр gridsize.

Comment: neverd1m, gridSize - это совсем не то... тут идёт группировка по району, а  gridSize даже и рядом нет. Поэтому рекомендую тоже плотно ознакомится.

Answer (score 0):

Как я вижу, кластеризация объектов по районам / областям сделана на сервере, а для отображения серверной кластеризации объектов используется [RemoteObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager.html). В частности, этому менеджеру можно передать массив объектов в составе кластера в поле features ([см. пример 2](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager.html#RemoteObjectManager__constructor-summary)).